# ASP.NET Version string portion was too short or too long. (Plesk)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, server, plesk

So I have a website that I uploaded on Plesk a couple of months ago, the website was working perfectly, until a couple of days ago it stopped and showed me the error of (Version string portion was too short or too long.) for absolutely no reason, I did not touch the code, I did not alter the web.config file, the error just came out of nowhere.

So far I have been looking for a solution and nothing has worked for me, I do not know the source of the problem, I'm using ASP.NET version 4.8, is the problem related to the web.config file? or the SQL database? I really have no clue.

Here's my web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  
  
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=SG2NWPLS14SQL-v06.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net;user id=****;password=****;initial catalog=Archive;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  
  
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
  
  
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    
    
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    
    
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    
    
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
  </system.webServer>
  
  
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  
  
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>    
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  
  
<system.codedom>
   <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
      
      
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  
  
  
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 498CD578-6069-45EF-8E61-D97397AC4744-->
```

and here's the error message:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

***Version string portion was too short or too long.***

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long.

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long.]
   System.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument) +12868600
   System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result) +438
   System.Version.Parse(String input) +69
   System.Version..ctor(String version) +28
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetVersionFromVString(String version) +75
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CreateCodeDomProviderWithPropertyOptions(Type codeDomProviderType) +123
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CreateCodeDomProviderNonPublic(Type codeDomProviderType) +14
   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder..ctor(CompilationSection compConfig, ICollection referencedAssemblies, CompilerType compilerType, String outputAssemblyName) +396
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() +707
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +30
   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +529
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) +131
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories() +398
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +256

[HttpException (0x80004005): Version string portion was too short or too long.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +65
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +458
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +35
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +605

[HttpException (0x80004005): Version string portion was too short or too long.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10087352
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263
```

**Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4330.0**

please if you know how to solve this let me know cz I'm really desperate :/

Comment: come on guys please any help, I've been suffering with this for a week now :(

Comment: Well, it's hard to believe that this kind of error can suddenly start to occur in an already deployed application. Most likely your application was not tested very well before. I would recommend to reproduce this issue on a local machine and look for more details about this error.